# Why is this Python regex negative look ahead not working?

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to collect a set of URLs, using BeautifulSoup, with a very specific criteria. The URLs I want to collect must contain `/b-\d+` (`/b-` followed by a series of numeric values). However, I want to ignore all URLs containing `View%20All` even if it has `/b-\d+` in it.
Here are a sample of URLs:

```
1. http://www.foo.com/bar/b-12312903?sName=View%20All
2. http://www.foo.com/bar/b-832173712873?sName=View%20All
3. http://www.foo.com/bar/b-1208313109283129
4. http://www.foo.com/bar/b-2198123371239489?adCell=W3
```

Given the above sample, the valid URLs that I want to collect are #3 and #4. I have tried using different negative lookahead regular expressions and they just aren't working for me:

```
{"href" : re.compile(r"\/b-\d+.+(?!View\%20All)")}
{"href" : re.compile(r"^.+\/b-\d+.+(?!View\%20All$)")}
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{"href" : re.compile(r"\/b-\d+.+(?!View\%20All)")}
{"href" : re.compile(r"^.+\/b-\d+.+(?!View\%20All$)")}
```

where you got wrong?

when we give `(?!View\%20All)` it asserts that the `View\%20All` cannot be matched immediately following the previous pattern which is `.+`

in effect it means that the look ahead is always true

to illustrate lets check what is matched at by each pattern

`http://www.foo.com/bar/b-12312903?sName=View%20All`

`/b-` is obvious

`\d` matches  `12312903`

now the problem arises,

`.+` matches anything such that it makes the negative assertion `(?!View\%20All)` successful.

that is say

`.` matches `?s` string that is left unmatched is  `sName=View%20All` which doesn't match `(?!View\%20All)` at the beginning position `s`hence always successful matching lines 1 and line 2

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/aS5yS2/2) to get a clear image.

Fix??

when using lookaround assertions, fix the positions from where  the checking starts

say using a regex like

```
(\/b-\d+)(\?|$)(?!sName=View\%20All)
```

which will match 3 and 4 as

http://regex101.com/r/aS5yS2/1

here `?` or `$` within the string fixes the position from where the negative assertion starts.

Answer (score 1):

```
^.*?/b-\d+(?:(?!View%20All).)*$
```

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/YoXWvr5tPI)

Or much faster

```
^.+?/b-\d+(?:[^V]+|V(?!iew%20All))*$
```

Comment: I dont understand why "." is needed at the end

also wow. that demo is awesome